# Is there a way to get Dell's lifecycle controller status from commandline?

Tags: linux, dell, lifecycle

Is there a way to get Dell's LifeCycle Controller status from command line?

For instance, there's a way to schedule BIOS configuration, but there's no way to check afterwards whether those tasks have been applied.

Is there a way to use `omreport` or something alike to find out whether LifeCycle controller has tasks pending, i.e. machine could use a reboot?

Comment: This is something I'd be working out with your Dell representative.

Comment: Why? These are all freely available tools, and yes, I can ask Dell the same, but how's that not fitting the generic sysadmin theme? It's not that Dell is that rare.

Comment: This is a totally valid question; not sure why the closevote/downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using RACADM to hit the DRAC, you should be able to :

1. Query the current BIOS level to see if it's what you want it to be

> `racadm get  BIOS.SysInformation.SystemBiosVersion`

2. Review the LC log to see what's happened

> ```
> racadm lclog view -i <number of records> -a <agent id> -c <category> -s <severity> -b <sub-category> -q <sequence no.> -n  <number of records> -r <start timestamp> -e <end timestamp>
> ```

3. Look at any pending actions

> `racadm jobqueue view`

You can run `racadm` from the local windows system, or from a management station; either way you have to be able to connect to the DRAC with the proper creds.

/Edit - of course, racadm is the BFMI (brute force massive ignorance) approach. If you like to code, you could hit the [DRAC with WSMAN](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2011/11/21/scripting-dell-idrac6-with-lifecycle-controller-remote-services) from your language of choice and play with the data/objects yourself.

Comment: But of course, `racadm jobqueue`, I'm just stupid. Thanks. Pity it's not very parseable, but that's the right direction :)

Comment: Added a more programming-y suggestion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Iwork4Dell.  For older generations of servers the racadm commands for managing jobs may not be avaliable.  On these systems you will need to use winrm or openwsman and the LC wsman interface. For more information and sample scripts refer to the Best Practices Guide on the http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/Lifecycle+Controller